# Alsa mixer and GtkVolumeButton

Tags: gtk, alsa

I make code to get and set alsa mixer volume:

```
snd_mixer_elem_t *elem = NULL;
long alsa_min, alsa_max, alsa_vol;

int alsa_get_volume( void )
{
    long val;
    assert (elem);

    if (snd_mixer_selem_is_playback_mono(elem)) {
        snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_volume(elem, SND_MIXER_SCHN_MONO, &val);
        return val;
    } else {
        int c, n = 0;
        long sum = 0;
        for (c = 0; c <= SND_MIXER_SCHN_LAST; c++) {
                if (snd_mixer_selem_has_playback_channel(elem, c)) {
                        snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_volume(elem, SND_MIXER_SCHN_FRONT_LEFT, &val);
                        sum += val;
                        n++;
                }
        }
        if (! n) {
                return 0;
        }
        val = sum / n;
        sum = (long)((double)(alsa_vol * (alsa_max - alsa_min)) / 100. + 0.5);
        if (sum != val) {
           alsa_vol = (long)(((val * 100.) / (alsa_max - alsa_min)) + 0.5);
        }
        return alsa_vol;
    }
}

int alsa_set_volume( int percentdiff )
{
    long volume;

    alsa_get_volume();

    alsa_vol += percentdiff;
    if( alsa_vol > 100 ) alsa_vol = 100;
    if( alsa_vol < 0 ) alsa_vol = 0;

    volume = (long)((alsa_vol * (alsa_max - alsa_min) / 100.) + 0.5);

    snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_volume_all(elem, volume + alsa_min);
    snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_switch_all(elem, 1);
    muted = 0;
    mutecount = 0;

    return alsa_vol;
}
```

I wont to make alsa mixer volume to changed by GtkVolumeButton. Tried this but when value from gtk button is changed up or down, alsa mixer always jumps to 100 %:

```
int gtk_volume_button_get_value (GtkWidget *button)
{
    return (int) (gtk_scale_button_get_value(GTK_SCALE_BUTTON(button)) * 100);
}

void gtk_volume_button_set_value (GtkWidget *button, int value)
{
    gtk_scale_button_set_value(GTK_SCALE_BUTTON(button), (gdouble) value / 100);
}

void volume_value_changed_cb(GtkVolumeButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    int vol = (int)(gtk_volume_button_get_value(volume_button) + 0.5);

    alsa_set_volume(vol);
}
```

Please help me to write a corect code for GtkVolumeButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with GtkVolume. In fact, it comes from you using two different approaches to handle volume. `alsa_get_volume` gives you an absolute sound level, which is an integer. One would expect `alsa_set_volume` to accept the same kind of value range. And that's how you use it in `volume_value_changed_cb`: « get the volume level of the volume control, between 0 and 100, and set it as current volume. ».

However, the implementation is completely different. It's implemented as if you wanted to tell it « add or substract x% of the current sound volume ». You get the current volume level and add that percentage, thus you're computing a relative sound level, not an absolute one. So, if your initial sound level is 50%, and you want to lower it to 45%, one would expect you'd call `alsa_set_volume (45)` to do it. But currently, calling `alsa_set_volume (45)` will set `alsa_vol` to 50 + 45 = 95%.

So you need to use absolute volume, not relative.

```
/* newvol: Desired volume level in the [0;100] range */
int alsa_set_volume (int newvol)
{
    long volume;

    alsa_vol = CLAMP(absvol, 0, 100);

    volume = (long)((alsa_vol * (alsa_max - alsa_min) / 100.) + alsa_min);

    snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_volume_all(elem, volume);
    snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_switch_all(elem, 1);
    muted = 0;
    mutecount = 0;

    return alsa_vol;
}
```